# Problem with mock setup for function with object parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock an instance of a logger for unit tests. Since I have a method with basically logging, I want to store the logs in a list of strings and then check if the actual logs are the expected ones. I'm doing this right now:

```
logDebug = new List<string>();

loggerMock
    .Setup(l => l.LogDebug(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
    .Callback((string str, object[] par) =>
    {
        logDebug.Add(str);
        return;
    });
```

But I get this error:

```
Error Message:
 System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: l => l.LogDebug(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>())
```

I've searched for this error on the internet but didn't find anything. I also tried with return but it's not working.

Thank you in advance,

Nicholas

Comment: _Invalid setup on an extension method_ - if `LogDebug` is extension method you will not be able to mock it.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you @Fabio . Do you know what is the alternative in that case?

Comment: You always can test actual implementation, log it and then write code to read logs and check it contains expected values.